# How to create a nested map Map<String, Map<String,String>> with Stream API

Tags: java, hashmap, java-stream, collectors

How can I write the logic to obtain a `Map<String, Map<String, String>>` using streams?

Here is the code I have tried :

```
public Map<String, Map<String, String>> getData(Set<String> Ids) {
    List<Events> events = repository.findAllByIdIn(Ids);

    int i = 0;
    return events.stream()
            .sorted(Comparator.comparing(Events::getMajor).thenComparing(Events::getMinor))
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Events::getId, 
    //Error-Cannot resolve method 'getMajor()'
    Collectors.mapping(cae -> cae.getMajor() + "." + cae.getMinor(), 
        cae.getDates().get(i).getEndDate() != null ? "Predicted" : "Not Predicted"), 
             Collectors.toMap())));//Error-Cannot resolve method 'toMap()'
}
```

So how do I loop through a map inside another map?

Comment: the second argument to `groupingBy` must be a `Collector`, but you provided a `Function`

Comment: hi @Lino, I have provided the argument but it still gives an error. What other way could I write this in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Collector [`toMap()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap(java.util.function.Function,java.util.function.Function)) contrary to collectors `toList()` and `toSet()` *isn't parameterless*, you need to provide information how a key and a value should be extracted from a single stream element.

`Collectors.toMap()` expects at least two *functions*: `keyMapper` and `valueMapper`. In case if there could be duplicates, you need to use the flavor of `toMap` which takes a `mergeFunction` as a third argument to resolve the values that collide on the same key.

So you need to place `toMap()` as a second argument (*downstream collector*) into the `groupingBy`. That will be a syntactically correct structure of the *collectors* and *functions*:

```
Collectors.groupingBy(classifier, Collectors.toMap(keyMapper, valueMapper))
```

And that how the code might look like:

```
return events.stream()
        .sorted(Comparator.comparing(Events::getMajor)
            .thenComparing(Events::getMinor))
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Events::getId,
            Collectors.toMap(cae -> cae.getMajor() + "." + cae.getMinor(),
                cae -> cae.getDates().get(i).getEndDate() != null ? 
                    "Predicted" : "Not Predicted")));
```

**Note**, `Collectors.mapping()` isn't meant to produce a `Map` but to *transform* the elements of the stream, you can think of it as an analog of the `map()` operation that is done not is the middle of the stream pipeline, but during the process of collecting the data.

And if I understood your logic correctly, there's no need to apply `mapping()` here.